# Jenkins-Poll Mailbox Trigger

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops, jenkins-cli, devops-services

Can we add(restrict) emailids who can only send emails to trigger jenkins job using jenkins  Poll Mailbox Trigger plugin.
As of now any body can send email who knows the subject and job gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

you can use job restriction plugin to restrict the jobs that who can trigger.
please see for yourself
[Job restriction plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Restrictions+Plugin)